# Extract a single string from a single cell using hive sql function

Tags: hive, extract

I have a cell which contains multiple string values separated by commas. I need to extract only a single string.
Example:
Cell Value: `[{id=111, title=Arun.P, jobTitle=Data Analyst}]`

Expected Outcome: Arun.P

```
SELECT regexp_extract(team member name, 'title=([^,]+)', 1) AS extracted_title
FROM table_a
```

Error:

> Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:21
> cannot recognize input near 'regexp_extract' '(' 'team' in expression
> specification

Answer (score 0):

Its kinda right, you can use the `REGEXP_EXTRACT` function to extract the substring based on a regex. Here's one syntax for your example that might work:

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_EXTRACT(`team member name`, 'title=([^,]+)', 1) AS extracted_title FROM table_a;
```

It matches the regex `'title=([^,]+)'` from the column named `team member name` in the `table_a` table. The regular expression captures the value following the 'title=' until a comma is encountered.

Make sure to use backticks around column names if they contain spaces or special characters.

This should give you the expected outcome. If you encounter any issues or if the data structure varies, you may need to adjust the regular expression accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The only problem looks like the way you specified the column name. I tried locally on Hive-4.x

```html
0: jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/> SELECT REGEXP_EXTRACT(`team member name`, 'title=([^,]+)', 1) AS extracted_title FROM table_a;
INFO  : Compiling command(queryId=hive_20240120205056_e3506542-af57-4f07-9db7-c437ff0d4a3d): SELECT REGEXP_EXTRACT(`team member name`, 'title=([^,]+)', 1) AS extracted_title FROM table_a
INFO  : Semantic Analysis Completed (retrial = false)
INFO  : Created Hive schema: Schema(fieldSchemas:[FieldSchema(name:extracted_title, type:string, comment:null)], properties:null)
INFO  : Completed compiling command(queryId=hive_20240120205056_e3506542-af57-4f07-9db7-c437ff0d4a3d); Time taken: 0.111 seconds
INFO  : Concurrency mode is disabled, not creating a lock manager
INFO  : Executing command(queryId=hive_20240120205056_e3506542-af57-4f07-9db7-c437ff0d4a3d): SELECT REGEXP_EXTRACT(`team member name`, 'title=([^,]+)', 1) AS extracted_title FROM table_a
INFO  : Completed executing command(queryId=hive_20240120205056_e3506542-af57-4f07-9db7-c437ff0d4a3d); Time taken: 0.001 seconds
+------------------+
| extracted_title  |
+------------------+
| Arun.P           |
+------------------+
1 row selected (0.165 seconds)
```

And it works.

I created the table like

```html
 create table table_a (`team member name` string)
```